# How do I open JavaFX projects in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Set up your JavaFX project in NetBeans IDE as follows.

1. From the File menu, choose New Project.
2. In the JavaFX application category, choose JavaFX Application. Click
   Next.

Why can't I the see JavaFX application category? How can i fix it? My Netbeans version is 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javafx-setup.html) on using NetBeans JavaFX support and configuring a NetBeans JavaFX platform.  Additionally, make sure you have [installed JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html).  Try with the latest [NetBeans nightly build](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/), as the NetBeans 7.1 build does have some bugs in it's JavaFX support.  If it still doesn't work, [file an issue](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) with NetBeans

JavaFX support for Macintosh and Linux is only in [early access form](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) at the moment and would be unlikely to work out the box in NetBeans 7.1, but *perhaps* could be made to work if you extracted the Macintosh or Linux JavaFX early access builds and followed the NetBeans JavaFX platform setup documentation.

Comment: i'm using windows 7.also have proxy enabled on the network. i did put proxy there also but still no effect. is there any other way, i means manually?

Comment: I don't know of another way. I suggest you file an issue with NetBeans.

Comment: It's not quite the same but if you wanted, you could try creating a normal Java Project, adding a new library to NetBeans which contains jfxrt.jar (from the JavaFX SDK runtime installation) and using that library in your project.  This will allow you to develop, compile and run projects which use JavaFX source.  If you also want to package the application for deployment, then use the JavaFX ant tasks.  You don't get all of the functionality of the NetBeans JavaFX integration, but it is enough to develop JavaFX software.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins. Press "Reload Catalog" and search for the "JavaFX 2 Support". Install it and restart Netbeans.

It should work now.

Comment: I did but still cann't find it after clicking on "Reload Catalog".

Comment: @itro Hmmm, that's very weird. Isn't there anything on that list that has "JavaFX" in the name ?

Comment: No there is nothing on the list that has "JavaFX".

Comment: i'm behind a proxy and i put my proxy there. can it be the reason?

Comment: @itro if the proxy works, it should be ok. Question: when you pressed the "Reload Catalog", did the list refresh ? Did it acquire more elements ?

Comment: No it does not add more elements.

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

JavaFX Plugins are deactivated, I activated them by this way.

Tools -> Plugins -> Installed (Tab) -> Select JavaFX plugins and click on Activate them.

JavaFX has been enabled in my NetBeans.