# JavaFX LineChart Error: "Instances of javafx.scene.chart.LineChart cannot be created by FXML loader. (Java 11, JavaFX 17)

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml, linechart

I am in the process of moving my JavaFX project from Java 8 to Java 11, JavaFX 17 for the past week or so. I also moved from Scenebuilder 8.5 to Scenebuilder JavaFX Version: 20.0.1. All in all it has been reasonably smooth, however I am facing a confusing error that I cannot seem to solve.

```
Instances of `javafx.scene.chart.LineChart` cannot be created by FXML loader.
```

When I changed the Java version of my project to Java 11, and imported the JavaFX 17 library to my project, The `LineChart` I am using in my project began throwing an error I had never seen before in the FXML Document file. It is a 330 line file so I will only include the relevant parts:

```
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>


<LineChart fx:id="chartDashboardLineChart" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="233.0" prefWidth="870.0" title="Monthly Sales">
   <xAxis>
     <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" fx:id="x" />
   </xAxis>
   <yAxis>
     <NumberAxis fx:id="y" side="LEFT" />
   </yAxis>
</LineChart>
```

The error is displayed under the line where the LineChart chartDashboardLineChart is declared. There are also two new errors which read: Class `javafx.scene.chart.LineChart` does not support property `xAxis` (and the same for  `yAxis`). These two errors seem less worrying to me than the FXML Loader error above.
I will also include the relevant lines of code from my project, although I believe it is more likely that the error lies within the FXML Document. Here is the Java Code (this is split across 2 different classes: [Class: LineCharts.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVsmZ.png)

And another class, this one too large to post in its entirety called DashboardController.java, Here are the relevant parts of the DashboardController class:

```
@FXML
private LineChart<?, ?> chartDashboardLineChart;
@FXML
private CategoryAxis x;
@FXML
private NumberAxis y;
LineCharts LC = new LineCharts();

//later on in the initialize area of the code

//Call the initializeLineChart method and pass the line chart as an argument
LC.generateDashboardLineChart(chartDashboardLineChart);
```

I have tried numerous things to try and fix this issue, but with no success. It seems it is a rare issue to have as there is little to no information that I could find online.

I appreciate any bit of help or any theories as to what is causing my issue, and how to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace? Also, why are you using wildcards in the declaration of the line chart in the controller?

Comment: And,  I suppose, clarify exactly where and when these errors occur. The error in the title is a runtime error generated when you try and run the application? Or when you try to run SceneBuilder? The "properties not supported" errors are "in the FXML file"? Meaning they just show up in the IDE?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate this either by running the app or in SceneBuilder.

Verify that the following code works in your environment.

**Test Environment**

Execution Environment:

```
OS X 13.4.1, JavaFX 20.0.2, OpenJDK 19.0.2
```

SceneBuilder Version (from the About screen):

```
Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 19.0.0

Build Information
Version 19.0.0
Date: 2022-10-07 07:42:50
JavaFX Version: 19
Java Version: 17, OpenJDK Runtime Environment
```

**Test Application**

*line-chart.fxml*

```
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>

<LineChart fx:controller="com.test.demo.chart.ChartController"
           xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" 
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" 
           fx:id="chartDashboardLineChart" 
           layoutX="5.0" layoutY="10.0" 
           prefHeight="233.0" prefWidth="870.0" 
           title="Monthly Sales">
    <xAxis>
        <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" fx:id="x" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis fx:id="y" side="LEFT" />
    </yAxis>
</LineChart>
```

*ChartController.java*

```
package com.test.demo.chart;

import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;

public class ChartController {
    public LineChart<String, Double> chartDashboardLineChart;
    public CategoryAxis x;
    public NumberAxis y;
}
```

*LineChartApp.java*

```
package com.test.demo.chart;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                LineChartApp.class.getResource(
                        "line-chart.fxml"
                )
        );

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        loader.load()
                )
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Output*

[image: monthly sales]

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this finding using MacOS 12.6, JDK 17.0.8, SceneBuilder 19, this [*Status Application*](https://github.com/trashgod/modular#status-application) or this [*Test Application*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76955914/230513), and NetBeans 18 with the JavaFX 2 v1.37 plugin mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611827/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9262029/230513). As the plugin is outmoded, deactivating it is a simple workaround. Doing so eliminates the (spurious) error and warnings.

[image: Plugins]

With reference to *line-chart.fxml* cite above:

```
 5: Instances of `javafx.scene.chart.LineChart` cannot be created by FXML loader.
12: Class `javafx.scene.chart.LineChart` does not support property `xAxis`.
15: Class `javafx.scene.chart.LineChart` does not support property `yAxis`.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange error; while the error still shows on netbeans (13) in the FXML Document, it seems that when I run the project the line chart works regardless. Here is a screenshot showing the errors on netbeans:

[image: Errors Screenshot]

Here is an image showing that it runs and displays the line chart regardless:!

[image: LineChart in action]

Thanks to everyone who posted a suggestion, I very much appreciate it. I still do not understand why errors are being displayed in the FXML Document, but ultimately it does not seem to be affecting my project.

Comment: I suspect the plugin mentioned illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76963655/230513) and re-tagged your question; please don't hesitate to edit your question accordingly; I'd welcome learning of your result.

Comment: Going forward, you can accept an answer by clicking on the [empty check mark](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/163188) at the answer's left.